# Accessing JavaScript object properties and functions giving undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in node. I'm trying to access object properties and methods with .notation and it is giving `undefined` error for object properties and `"TypeError: dice.roll is not a function "` for object functions.

Here is code:

**object file:**

```
var dice = {
    size: 4,
    count:3,    
    roll:function(){
        var result = Math.ceil(this.size * Math.random());
        return result;
    } 
};
exports.diceObjectName = dice;
```

**program file:**

```
var dice = require("./dice");    
console.log(dice);    
console.log(dice.roll());
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(dice)` ?

Comment: Try to change `exports.diceObjectName = dice;` into `exports.dice = dice;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting your object inside diceObjectName. So in order to use it you have to do so:

```
var dice = require("./dice").diceObjectName;
```

[Example](https://repl.it/repls/DownrightPreciousRedstart)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `module.exports = dice`

```
var dice = {
    size: 4,
    count:3,    
    roll:function(){
        var result = Math.ceil(this.size * Math.random());
        return result;
    } 
};

module.exports = dice;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code: `exports.diceObjectName = dice;` try this: `module.exports = dice`

or this:

```
var dice = require("./dice").diceObjectName;    
console.log(dice);    
console.log(dice.roll());
```